# Can the browser and web-browser tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The questions tagged [browser](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) are all related to [web-browser](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser).

There isn't a point in keeping the two seperate, especially since [browsers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browsers) is a synonym for web-browser.

Comment: I agree, it is done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I second this one. I highly doubt that that there will be questions about browsers that aren't web browsers.

ABOLISH THE [browser](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) TAG!